# Filter vinyl records by type

Tags: haskell, vinyl

Using the vinyl library, is there a way to filter out a set of records by either their type, or some other property? I want to be able to mix in the values of shader uniforms with other properties of my objects, and be able to extract them later to call `Graphics.VinylGL.Uniforms.setAllUniforms` on. I would rather not use `HList` because IMO vinyl is nicer.

Comment: Hmm. The 'type' of a record in Vinyl is a promoted value - e.g. `"foo" ::: Int` - presumably you just want to filter on the `Int` part?

Comment: Yes. Or ideally anything wrapped in some specific `newtype`.

Comment: I ended up using a `newtype` and `OverlappingInstances`.

Comment: @Dan could you answer your question? Maybe with some code, I'm curious about your solution.